# Relations between eigenvalues of product and its factors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let A,B be symmetric matrices of order $n\geq2$. Also, A is positive
>   definite.
>
> 1. If B is positive definite, the AB has only positive eigenvalues.
> 2. If eigenvalues of AB are non-negative, then B is positive semidefinite.

Please, give me a hint how to prove these claims?

Comment: Look at all the Related problems running down the side of the page. I bet this question is answered in one of them.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$AB$ is similar to $\sqrt A B \sqrt A$, that is simmetrical and is (semi) positive definite iff $B$ is

Comment: How do you know that AB is similar ot $\sqrt(A) B \sqrt(A)$?

Comment: There's an easy similitude between them

Comment: $A$ is positive definite, hence invertible. So is $\sqrt A$. Thus
$$AB=\sqrt A\cdot \sqrt AB\sqrt A\cdot \sqrt A^{-1}$$

Comment: @Berci, thanks, now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

If $A,B$ are positive definite matrices, then their eigenvalues must be positive. Taking the diagonal form you see that the product of them has the eigenvalues of the form $\lambda_i\mu_i$ where $\lambda_i>0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $\mu_i>0$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. Of course, you have to explain it in more details, but I think it is one possible way.

Similar way to consider for the second claim. The only difference is that now $\mu_i\geq 0$ for the semidefinite $B$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm.. It's true only if they're diagonalizable with the same orthogonal matrix..

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will try a different approach in few minutes.

Comment: @Sixim, I thought about that way, but A,B may not be diagonalizable in the same basis. So I don't think I can consider the product of eigenvalues.

Comment: It seems that my other approach also fails, so I do not post it as edition. Anyway, I do not delete the answer, so others can see, the reason why the idea is not applicable. Sorry for that...